# Defining a function to calculate mean-differences at specific array size

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have an array:

```
arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

I want to define a function to calculate the difference of means of the elements of this array but at a given length.

For example:

```
diff_avg(arr, size=2)
```

**Expected Result:**

```
[-2, -2]
```

because:

```
((1+2)/2) - ((3+4)/2)) = -2 -> first 4 elements because size is 2, so 2 groups of 2 elements
((5+6)/2) - ((7+8)/2)) = -2 -> last 4 elements
```

`if size=3`

then:

```
output: [-3]
```

because:

```
((1+2+3)/3) - ((4+5+6)/3)) = -3 -> first 6 elements
```

**what I did so far:**

```
def diff_avg(first_group, second_group, size):
    results =[]
    x = np.mean(first_group) - np.mean(second_group)
    results.append(x)
    return results
```

I don't know how to add the size parameter

I can use the first **size** elements with `arr[:size]` but how to get the next **size** elements.

Does anyone can help me?

Comment: What if your array does not have enough items? (As in the second example.)

Comment: in the second example the last 2 items are ignored, that's why there's only one value in the output. maybe, if there's no enough items to get at least one result, then an error msg can pop up to tell there's not enough elements. for that size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, truncate the array to remove the extra items:

```
size = 3
sized_array = arr[:arr.size // (size * 2) * (size * 2)]
# array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Next, reshape the sized array and get the means:

```
means = sized_array.reshape([2, size, -1]).mean(axis=1)
# array([[2.], [5.]])
```

Finally, take the differences:

```
means[0] - means[1]
#array([-3.])
```